# OS X El Capitan is losing connection to Active Directory

Tags: mac-osx, mac

I have successfully joined three iMacs to our Active Directory. Everything is working well except one thing. Every time when the iMac goes to its screensaver, we can't log back in. The screen shakes as if the password entered is wrong (which after five attempts would lock the network account) which it never does because it's not ''talking'' to the Active Directory.

The only solution is to reboot or go to the switch user tab and reconnect to my account (it is a mobile account). I see the same issue on my three iMacs.

Power saving is disabled. Do any of you have this problem ? 10.11.6 is my current OS X version.

The connection is lost ten minutes after a boot up, no matter if the screensaver is on or power saving. It might be related to our AD.

```
2016-10-27 09:37:26.534823 EDT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 426.1137.1141.1142, Node: /Active Directory/**AD**/**DOMAIN**, Module: ldap - failed GSSAPI authentication for authzid - 'u:imac-606381$' authcid - 'imac-606381$' error -2
```

Comment: This is pretty board, and doesn't really contain a question...  What have you tried already?  When they are in the state where you feel they've lost connection to AD, do they still answer pings?  Did you happen to clone the disk of one iMac to the other 2 while preparing them/setting them up?

Comment: All my iMacs are brand new, fresh install. I can log with my network account from a reboot , but if I let the iMac lock himself , I can't unlock it.

Comment: Also , in the printer tabs , there is a complete list of all printers in our AD. When the login problem occurs and I can't log back ( i have to use the switch user button ) and log from the mobile account that is '' cached'' on the mac , the printer list disapers and I can't search any printer from the AD. When the iMac locks I'm losing exactly 1 ping and I'm pretty sure that's when the problem occurs.

Comment: Are the machines connected via wire or wireless? Any entries related to the Mac in the DC's event logs around the time the problem happens?

Comment: Also, which server(s) are set as the DNS servers on the Macs?

Comment: They are all wired ! They have a proper dns entry ( in a 172.16/12 subnet ) and the DC are in 10/8 ) DC are reachable and dns can be solved.

Comment: I don't have acces to DC logs , but I reading logs in /var/logs/opendirectoryd.log and there is something weird I will give it a look tomorrow. My last chance is to upgrade to MacOS sierra which I don't feel confident doing this over 30+ macs...

Comment: After troubleshooting many things ,  the issue is not related to Sleep or Screen saver.

Comment: Have you considered cross-posting to apple.stackexchange.com? May find more help there.

Comment: I did ! It appers that Active Directory ( or OSX If I'm wrong ) is having a hard time accessing my password or Kerberos Ticket from Keychain. Sometimes it works , sometimes it doesnt ( talking about the error discribed up.